# Rails/Ruby Over ride to_s for array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails form i am using a multi select tag

code looks like

```
  <%= select_tag '[mycontroller][users]', @users, { :multiple => true, :size => 7} %>
  <p><%= submit_tag l(:button_apply)%></p>
```

On form submit parameters passed are

```
 mycontroller[users][]=79&mycontroller[users][]=80&commit=Apply
```

Now in my view file when i retrieve params they are being converted to string
so i get [79,80] being converted to "7980"

code for getting user param looks like

```
users =  params[:mycontroller][:users] unless params[:mycontroller].nil?
```

*Edit*:

Problem i suppose is that "#{}" converts array to string. even <%= %> will call to_s

So how to override this? So that to_s will return "79,80" instead of "7980"

What am i missing? 
Comments, please?

Thnx.

Comment: notice: when used wisely, `try` is very handy: `users =  params[:mycontroller].try(:[],:users)`.

Comment: nice suggestion, @apneadiving. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call array.join(",") and a array of [79,80] should become a string like "79,89"

[Ruby Join Method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join)

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `to_s` seems very heavy handed.

You can either iterate through the array displaying each element individually (usually more readable if you're presenting something complicated for each element,  or use something like `my_array.join(',')` if you just want to comma separate the array elements.

Comment: thnx @Frederick, this was too simple. thnx for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I dint know that Array.join returns string, so i was trying to solve it in my own way.
This may not be efficient/effective but its a workaround.

```
arr = [79,80]
a =arr.inject(0){|op,i| op.to_s + i.to_s + ","}.to_s  
a[1,a.length-2] # "79,80"
```

Comment: This won't behave the same on ruby 1.9,  where to_s is aliased to inspect